# Mercurial pre-merge hook

Tags: c, mercurial, merge

Is there a way to do some checks before allowing a merge in Mercurial?

I have found the pre-update hook and have a script that runs before an update is allowed, by adding the following to `~/.hg/hgrc`:

```
[hooks]
pre-update = ~/hg_pre_update.sh
```

But I'd like to run the check before allowing a merge as well, and currently it just allows the merge to go through without running my checks.

**Background**

In case there are alternative ways to solve the problem...

We have been having a number of problems with 'lost' edits under Mercurial.  I've tracked down most of them now to the same underlying cause: someone has vim edit sessions open while either they or someone else does a hg update or merge.  The editor warns the file has changed externally, the user ignores the warning and saves their changes.

When these changes are committed, for Mercurial there is nothing controversial.  The user has simply reverted all the changes brought in with the last update and put in their own changes.

Some time later, we notice the code has gone walkabouts.  Cue assorted insults flung the way of mercurial...

Comment: I would direct my insults not at the source control tool but at the other tools.

Comment: Or, actually, at the user that ignored the warning that the file has changed on the disk and just went with the one in the editor.

Comment: Oh yes, that is who my insults are directed at!

Answer (score 1):

Set vim to autoreload changes if no local changes where done. (otherwise ask, or force a merge)

that's how I avoid such issues in any editor...

Comment: It's not me having the problem (well the original problem) and I can't control how other people are using the editor.  The problems I have seen were always where there were local changes as well, so I'm not certain this would help much.

Comment: They need to learn to save their work and commit (or shelve) it before doing a merge.  It is simply part of the process of using source control.

Comment: asc99x: Ugh. To check in the script that the editor has unsaved changes before update/merge sounds tricky, unless it's integrated into the editor (like in Eclipse / Visual Studio / Emacs (probably...). Vim? Dunno.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry just worked out there is a `pre-merge` hook that works just the same as `pre-update`.  I tried it before asking the question, but now just looking at my hgrc I realise I put the script being called for that hook to `~/hg_pre_merge.sh` which doesn't exist.

I can't find the existence of pre-merge documented anywhere but still feeling like a bit of a muppet now.

[image: Feeling like a bit of a muppet now.]

Comment: Just out of interest.. what will that hook do to protect against this issue?

Comment: All the troublemakers here use vim, so the hook looks for the temporary files left open by vim sessions (`~/.*.swp`) and quits before starting the merge.  There are about 4 people sharing the same central dev system and quite frequently one of them does a merge while the others are in the middle of working.  And when it comes time to commit, none of them really know what they're committing since most of it is other people's work, so they don't realise file X shouldn't have changed...

Comment: @asc99c: Excellent.. Put that in the question. :) Butbutbut... do several people develop simultaneously on the same machine/workingdir? O_O

Comment: Yes!  Traditionally that is how we all worked and there has been immense resistance to changing it.  I've been trying to push Mercurial for a while and it is starting to gain traction.   But on this team we've still got 2 dedicated holdouts who want everyone to work on the same central server, and 2 more who are starting to sway towards mercurial I hope.  At least mercurial can just about cope - the holdouts killed any chance of Subversion getting a foothold.